# When we say that $\mathbb S^1$ is compact, which topology we are thinking about?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $$f:[0,2\pi)\to \mathbb S^1$$ defined as $$f(t)=e^{it}.$$
Then $f$ is continuous and bijective, but the inverse is not continuous because $f^{-1}(\mathbb S^1)=[0,2\pi)$ and $\mathbb S^1$ is compact whereas $[0,2\pi[$ it's not.

Q1) What is the definition of $\mathbb S^1$ ? Is it $\{e^{it}\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\}$ ? Is it $\{(\cos \theta ,\sin\theta )\mid \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}$ ? Or is it the quotient space $[0,1]/_\sim$ where $0\sim 1$ and $x\sim x$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ ?

Q2) So when we say it's compact, it's wrt which topology ? quotient ? metric ? btw what would be a metric on $\mathbb S^1$ ?

Im confused...

Comment: I don't think there is "the one" definition, there are many equivalent models good for different things. A particular text or paper may take one as the "basic" model, but since they are all homeomorphic, it doesn't really matter which one "is" $\mathbb S^1$.

Comment: Do you know what the „subspace topology“ is? It's a pretty important concept for this question.

Comment: The topology I would take is the topology that the set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ has as closed subset of the Euclidean topological space $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: When I think of $S^1$, I invariably think of either $\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$ or $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$. These are both homeomorphic, so topologically speaking, it’s the same thing. You can see that it’s compact (if you believe the norm is continuous) since it is the preimage of the closed set $\{1\}$.

Comment: @JustinYoung: When I was at EPFL, I follow a course of topology and my teacher was Justin Young... maybe you are this person :-)

Comment: @JustinYoung : "since they are all homeomorphic" : all topology of $\mathbb S^1$ are homeomorphic ? even to ($\mathbb S^2$,T_{discrete})$ ? I don't get the point here.

Comment: @Clayton: that a good point, thank you.

Comment: @USER386627 no. the space doesn't get to be an $\mathbb S^1$ unless it is homeomorphic to your models mentioned in question 1.

Comment: @Surb That was me!! I hope you weren't the one who wrote "pire prof de toute ma vie" in the comments! It haunts me to this day... That was a fun class quand même.

Comment: @JustinYoung: haha, good news :-) Not at all, I really enjoyed your courses :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want that the definition of $S^1$ makes sense, define it as$$\left\{e^{it}\,\middle|\,t\in[0,2\pi]\,\right\}$$(or $t\in[0,2\pi)$ or $t\in\mathbb R$ or …).
2. The topology induced by the usual distance in $\mathbb C$:$$d(z,w)=\lvert z-w\rvert.$$

Comment: "If you want that the definition of $S^1$ makes sense". What do you mean by "make sense" ?

Comment: @user386627 If you define $S^1$ as, say, $[0,1]/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that you defined, then you can't define $f$ as you did, right? Because $e^{it}\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes indeed... but using $\{e^{it}\mid t\in [0,2\pi)\}$ it's still compact ? Because it doesn't look to be close ($2\pi$ is not reached). Sorry I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @user386627 Since$$\left\{e^{it}\,\middle|\,t\in[0,2\pi]\,\right\}=\left\{e^{it}\,\middle|\,t\in[0,2\pi)\,\right\},$$either both spaces are compact or none of them is.

Comment: thank you. and for the metric $d(w,z)=|w-z|$ doesn't look very adapted. Isn't $d(z,w)=|\arg(z)-\arg(w)|$ much better ?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{arg}(z)$? If $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, is $\operatorname{arg}(e^{i\theta})=\theta$? If so, then, with the distance that you suggested, $S^1$ will **not** be compact, and it **will** be homeomorphic with $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Oh, waaaouuu... incredible ! I would never have suspect that. (yes $arg(z)=\theta $ where $z=e^{i\theta }$.) But if I talk $d(z,w)=|\arg(z)-\arg(w)|$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, then it will be compact, no ?

Comment: @user386627: You can't take $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. If so, the function $z\longmapsto \arg(z)$ won't be well defined.

Comment: @Surb: What do you mean ? The argument is always defined "modulo $2\pi$), for example $0$, $2\pi$, $4pi$ are the same angles... What do you mean by "$\arg(z)$ is not well defined" ?

Comment: @user386627 Because then$$0=\operatorname{arg}(e^{i\times0})=\operatorname{arg}(e^{i\times2\pi})=2\pi.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Yes, it's true since $0=2\pi$ for angles... so it's well defined (I don't see the point).

Comment: @user386627 We are talking about **numbers** here, not angles. And the number $0$ is different from the number $2\pi$.

Comment: Just last question : do you agree that $[0,1]/_{\sim}$ with $0\sim 1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1$ ? And thus $[0,1]/_{\sim}$ is metrizable, hausdorff...

Comment: @user386627 Yes, no doubt about it.